# Differential version of $G\mapsto H^3(G,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, conformal-field-theory, differential-cohomology

Let $\mathit{cLieGrp}^{\mathrm{inj}}$ be the category of compact connected Lie groups, and injective continuous group homomorphisms.
Is there a reasonable functor (some kind of degree $3$ differential cohomology?)
$$
F:\mathit{cLieGrp}^{\mathrm{inj}} \to \mathit{Ab}
$$
to the category of abelian groups with the following features:

(1) On the full subcategory of compact semisimple Lie groups, this functor agrees with $G\mapsto H^3(G,\mathbb Z)$ (integral 3rd cohomology of the underlying manifold of $G$).

(2) On the full subcategory of compact abelian Lie groups (tori), this functor agrees with $T\mapsto H^4(BT,\mathbb R)$.

---

Motivation for the question:
The functor $$G \mapsto \{ \text{full WZW models with gauge group } G\}$$ seems to behave like the functor $F$ above (except that the set of full WZW models with gauge group $G$ needs to be group-completed in order to make it into an abelian group).

Comment: Does "injective maps" mean "injective continuous group homomorphisms"? or "injective continuous maps" (or anything else)?

Comment: Well, $H^3(T,Z)=Z$ and $H^4(BT,R)=R$, this looks impossible...

Comment: By the way I meant $T=S^1$ in the above.

Comment: @YCor. Yes: I meant "injective continuous group homomorphisms".

Comment: @user43326. For $T:=S^1$, we have $H^3(T,\mathbb Z)=0$. It's just the cohomology of the underlying manifold (and as the manifold is 1-dimensional, there is no $H^3$).

Comment: OK, I thought you meant "group cohomology". But in that case it still doesn't work since $H^4(BT,R)$ is still different from $H^3(T,Z)$.  Or here does $B$ mean something other than the classifying space?

Comment: @user43326. The classes of groups covered under cases (1) and (2) are disjoint. So there is no contradiction. The group $S^1$ is not semisimple.

Comment: Oh, I.see.  There still is a problem.  The inclusion of the maximal torus of a semi-simple Lie group is a morphism in your category, right?  So such a cohomology theory can't possess Becker-Gottlieb type transfer.

Comment: @user43326 Yes, the inclusion $\iota:T \to G$ of a torus into a semi-simple Lie group is a morphism in $\mathit{cLieGrp}^{\mathrm{inj}}$. In that case, I would expect $F(\iota)$ to be $H^3(G,\mathbb Z) \to H^3(G,\mathbb R)\cong H^4(BG,\mathbb R) \to H^4(BT,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: The point is when the source is torsion-free, if there is transfer, the image should be the invariant of the target under the action of the Weil group.